# Why can't we define the naturals transformation between $C \rightarrow D$ functor and $C \rightarrow E$ functor

Tags: category-theory

In CWM (and other text books), natural transformations are defined between functors $ F : C \to D $ and $ G : C \to D $, that is to say, functors whose destinations are the same Category $D$.

Why do we need this limit? Can't we define the natural transformations between functors $ F : C \to D $ and $ G : C \to E $?

Without the limit of destination, I think we can define the natural transformations as the functor $\eta : D \to E $ like:

---

Assume:

$ C $ : Subcategory of $ Sets $ so objects of $ C $ are sets, and arrows of $C$ are functions.

(But I would like to remove this assumption)

$ F : C \to D $ (functor)

$ G : C \to E $ (functor)

$ X,Y \in Obj_C $

Then:

Natural transformation is a functor $\eta : D \to E $, such that:

for any Arrow $ f : X \to Y $ in Category $C$,

$ \eta((F(f))(F(x))) = (G(f))(\eta(F(x))) $ for any $ x \in X $

---

To define the equation in the last line, I assumed that $ X $ has elements. Is there any way to remove this assumption?

Comment: What you wrote doesn't seem to make sense. What is $X$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. X and Y are objects in Category C.

Comment: Are you suggesting that an object $X$ has elements?

Comment: Yes. I considered that Sets as C. But I think I have to rewire it more generally...

Comment: If $X$ is an object and $F$ is a functor, then $F(X)$ is an object and hence $F(f)F(X)$ does not make sense.

Comment: I think $F(X)$ is a object in $ D $, and F(f) is a morphism in D, so (F(f))(F(X)) makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: I added the parentheses for F(f) and G(f)

Comment: What do you mean by $(F(f))(F(X))$?

Comment: I mean $ F(f) $ is a arrow from $ G(X) $ to $ G(Y) $ in Category $ D $, because $ F $ is a functor from $ C $ to $ D $. Also, $ F(X) $ means a object in D. So, I would like to mean (F(f))(F(X)) is a object in D. Hmm....Oh, this is not a valid syntax. I changed to (F(f))(F( **x** )) for any $x \in X$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I noticed that I also assumed that arrows of $C$ are functions! $F(f)$ is a function, so we can apply argument $F(x) \in F(X)$ to this function, then get a element of a object $ G(Y) $ in Category $ E $. I compared the equality between these elements at the last equation.

Comment: Your definition doesn't really make sense (for instance, what is "$F(x)$"??), but you appear to trying to just define a functor $\eta:D\to E$ such that $G=\eta\circ F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kan extensions might be what you're thinking of:

Given two functors $F:\mathscr{C} \rightarrow \mathscr{D}$ and $G:\mathscr{C} \rightarrow \mathscr{E},\space$ a left Kan extension G along F is a functor $Lan _{F}\space G:\mathscr{D} \rightarrow \mathscr{E}$ together with a natural transformation $\eta:G\Rightarrow Lan _{F}\space G \cdot F$ such that for any other pair $ ( H:\mathscr{D} \rightarrow \mathscr{E},\epsilon:G\Rightarrow HF)$, $\space \epsilon \space$ factors uniquely through $\eta. \space$  That is, $\space \exists! \alpha:Lan _{F}\space G\Rightarrow H\space $ such that $\space \epsilon= \alpha _{F} \cdot \eta   . \space $(Riehl; CHT: Definition 1.1.1)

I believe you can find the better part of a chapter devoted to them in CWM!